# Driver speed does not change #frame

Tags: animation, constraints, drivers

I am driving an animated object on a curve through a follow path constraint via #frame in the offset.
When I try to slow it down by typing #frame/10 or #frame/100 the speed does not change.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

When you write `#frame` in a value, it creates a driver that will use the variable `frame` as scripted expression.

Once that driver is created, you should write `frame` without `#`, as this is the actual variable name.
Think of `#frame` as meaning "make a driver with `frame` in it".